# Trying to see if username is in the database once I'm logged in?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I went through multiple processes of trying to accomplish this, but couldn't quite figure it out. I went on Stack Overflow to find duplicate answers. I found some and try to adjust them into my code. Still no use. I'm trying to say if I'm logged in go to the profile page and if a username is in the database, I want you to display their name. If not in the database, then just don't show anything. Here is what I came up with:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>=1){
        echo "User was found in the database";
    }
    else{
        echo "User was not found in the database.";
    }
}
```

So the if isset user_id basically says if I'm logged in then do this. The code after that is trying to find if a username is found in that database. If so then say it's found. If not, then don't. I hope this was clear! Thank you!

EDIT: Here is the HTML Code:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    include_once('dbconnect.php');
    ?>

        <div class="banner_container">
            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <?php 


        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_POST['username'])){

    if(($_SESSION['user_id'] != "") && ($_POST['username'] != "")){
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND user_id !=".$user_id;
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo "User was found in the database";
        }
        else{
            echo "User was not found in the database.";
        }
    }
    else{
       echo "Username or user Id is empty";
    }

}
        ?>

        <?php 
            echo "<h1>";
            echo $_SESSION['first_name'];
            echo " ";
            echo $_SESSION['last_name'];
            echo "</h1>";
            echo "<p>";
            echo '"';
            echo $_SESSION['quote'];
            echo '"';
            echo "<br>";
            echo $_SESSION['who'];
            echo "</p>";

        ?>
        </div>
    </div>


<li><a href="http://www.quotin.co">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="quotin_about"> About</a></li>
                    <li class="qotd"><a href="quotin_qotd"> Quote of the Day</a></li>
                    <li class="all_categories"><a href="quotin_categories">All Categories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.quotin.co/quotin_authors"> Authors</a></li>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
                        echo $_SESSION['user_id'];

                        echo '<li id="active" class="dropdown">';
                        echo '<a id="act_color" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">';
                        echo $_SESSION['first_name'];
                        echo "'s";
                        echo ' ';
                        echo "Profile";
                        echo '<b class ="caret"></b></a>';
                        echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
                        echo '<li><a href="profile.php"> Profile</a></li>';
                        echo '<li><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>';
                        echo '</ul>';
                        echo '</li>';
                        echo '</a>';
                        echo '</li>';
                        } else {
                        }
                    ?>
```

This is the profile page that I'm on.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_POST['username'])){

    if(($_SESSION['user_id'] != "") && ($_POST['username'] != "")){
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND user_id !=".$user_id;
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo "User was found in the database";
        }
        else{
            echo "User was not found in the database.";
        }
    }
    else{
       echo "Username or user Id is empty";
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Undefined index: username` error and `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result` @ChandraKumar

Comment: Ok as soon as you said that I quickly researched on examples. Honestly, I don't understand. Could you help me to check if the $_POST['username'] is empty?

Comment: That's odd. It's not echoing anything now.  Why is that?

Comment: In this code you are using `$_POST['username']` where is post request to get `$_POST['username']`..

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I tried to do something different because nothing was showing up. I'll reinsert it

Comment: ? Are you there?

Comment: Are you submit username from other page for this `$_POST['username']`

Comment: On my login file and register I have `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);` if that's what you're talking about